# Remote debugger not breaking - rdebug-ide - RubyMine 6

Tags: ruby, remote-debugging, rubymine, rdebug

Just installed RubyMine 6 this week and tried to do remote debugging on an ubuntu server.

I am running this command on the server:

rdebug-ide -d –host 0.0.0.0 –port 8080 –dispatcher-port 3389 – bin/rails s

If I try to add breakpoints in the IDE I get the usual:
30564:

If I access the rails app the breakpoint is completely bypassed.

Debug gems installed on server:
debugger (1.6.2)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.4)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre15)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22)

Debug gems installed on client running rubymine:
debugger (1.6.2)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.4, 1.2.3)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre15)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.22)

Debugging on localhost works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to use `rdebug-ide` you need to remove `debugger`, an other option is to use `debugger-xml` with `debugger`, but that didn't work out for me, it cause a lot of errors locally on my machine and my coworkers when `resque` is working.

Comment: It is currently being looked at by the RM team: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14635